# Add More Fields to Users Pages (Admin Panel)

Tags: custom-field, admin, users, user-registration, core

So I'm trying to create some custom fields for users. I need to give users access to a 30 day trial of some software and I want to keep track of that in the users page of administration panel. If the user is in the trail I want to add "Trial" at the top and "Yes" or "No" next to the username on the All Users page. I'm assuming this would be a core file somewhere, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Don't ever edit core files :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook `manage_users_columns` to add (and I suppose remove) columns from the All users display. [This tutorial](http://w4dev.com/wp/display-users-login-time) details that.

You might be able to hook `user_edit_form_tag` to do the trial vs not trial at the top...but I'm not sure, you'd have to tinker with it. I think you'll probably end up having to use something else (`WP_Error` might be a good way to go), but that would be where I started.